# How to convert Bitcoin mnemonic to Monero mnemonic?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, mymonero, c++

I am working on a crypto wallet which supports both Bitcoin and Monero. Wallet first generates a BIP-39 mnemonic and after that mnemonic is used to generate a public and a secret key for Bitcoin.

I want a similar thing for Monero but using the same Mnemonic which is of 12 words. I know how to generate wallets keys and address from 13-word Mnemonic using mymonero-core-cpp code.

So in short my question is that "Is there a way to convert the BIP-39 12 words mnemonic to 13 words mnemonic by appending the checksum or whatever Monero uses in its protocol"?

Comment: I do believe that Monero uses a 25 word seeds, last one being a checksum.  Also not sure i'd want a single seed for all my different coins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your wordlists match, the 13th word is just a checksum word. You concatenate the prefixes of the main 12 words, run a checksum over it, mod that with the word count and, hey presto, you have the index of the word to use as your 13th word.

Example from luigi1111 [here](https://github.com/luigi1111/xmr.llcoins.net/blob/9307709d4b417c5b26df873d7f655e17718540be/site/js/mnemonic.js#L10) which shows creating the checksum

Note that the official Monero wallets makes use of 25 word versions nowadays as these offer much higher entropy.